# Adding a pure JS library to Ionic / Angular using NPM

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm trying to include one of these :

[He-Date](https://github.com/abrahamos/he-date)

[HebCal](https://github.com/hebcal/hebcal-js/)

To my Ionic app to be able to transform gregorian dates to hebrew calendar and the other way around.

I'm having a very hard time understanding how to import a script like this (that is pure JS) to my app. I tried to follow [Ionic's tutorial](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/third-party-libs/) and looked all over the web but didn't seem to find anything concrete. When following the tutorial, I add

```
import HeDate from 'he-date';
```

for example to my component, but `new HeDate()` can't be used after that so I guess something is missing.

What I mostly want to understand : how to add ANY pure JS to an angular app ?

Comment: I finally succeeded having it work by following these steps : https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-add-external-javascript-library-in-ionic2-application/87669/3 BUT I'm sure it's not the right way to do it.

Comment: instead of adding in index.html, you suggest to include in 'scripts' (angular.json)

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow these steps

include the external js file in angular.json under 'scripts' section

```
import * as hedate from 'HeDate';

declare var getMonthName: any;

getMonthName() // calling the method exist in hedate.js
```

Comment: I did `import * as hd from 'he-date';` and `declare var HeDate: any;` but then in constructor `var heDate = new HeDate(5777, 5, 15);` - ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: HeDate is not defined. There is a `package.json` file I used to add in "scripts" but I'm not sure whether it's the right place.

Comment: you need to include HeDate.js file under 'scripts' section in angular.json

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's accurate for an app that uses only angular; Though for Ionic it won't work :) There is no `angular.json`

Comment: instead of angular.json. you can include in index.html if it is ionic